# Why is memcpy needed in particular case

Tags: c

In the following function:

```
void cp (char **x, char ** y) {
    while (*x) {
        * y = malloc(strlen (*x)+1);
        // * y++ = *x++;
        memcpy (*y++, *x++, strlen (*x) + 1);
    }
}
```

Why do I need to use `memcpy`? Why can't I just use `* y++ = * x++`. When I try doing it that way, I get a segfault when trying to free that memory.

Comment: No sequence point, No ordered evaluation of arguments.

Comment: ... and the`strlen()` is pathetic, anyway. Just use `strcpy(*y++,*x++):` here [or`*y++ = strdup(*x++);`, avoiding the `strlen()` ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` and `y` are `char**`s. If you just do `* y++ = * x++`, then you're making the intermediate pointers point to the same place, rather than actually copying the data from the first location to the second.